# How to install Tails on a multi partition drive

Tags: tails

I have a USB drive that has more than one partition, and there is enough space for Tails in one of the partitions. How do I install Tails on a specific partition that's on that USB drive without deleting the other partitions/files?

Answer (score 0):

Tails should be used as a live USB or in a virtual machine. If you check the Tails website, you will not find instructions on how to install it to a disk because that's not how it is meant to be used.

https://tails.boum.org/install/linux/index.en.html